# How much take a time to load 1GB csv file into MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How much take a time to load 1GB csv file into MySQL?

***System Configuration:-
4GB RAM
Windows 2007***

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much of an idea about windows, but if you can ensure that your biggest single table fits in the storage engine buffer pool, it should not take more than 30 - 45 minutes (worst case) even with your given system configuration.